# Reading multiple row headers in a excel using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the excel which contains the student test details using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx',skiprows=3)
print(frame)
```

there are 3 extra rows those I am skipping. But the problem is I have the same headers repeated for each student.

```
  A        B          C         D           E

  Class   First
        StudentID   0001    StudentName   Name
                  DateOfTest  TestTitle   TestMarks  TestDuration
                  12/02/2019    Eng           97        12:30:00
                  13/02/2019    Mat           91        12:30:00
                  14/02/2019    Phy           81        12:30:00
  Class   Second
        StudentID   0002    StudentName   Name
                  DateOfTest  TestTitle   TestMarks  TestDuration
                  12/02/2019    Eng           67        12:30:00
                  13/02/2019    Mat           41        12:30:00
                  14/02/2019    Phy           81        12:30:00
```

using the above code I can read all the data as a single frame but I need multiple frames. How Can I read each student's test details and it's helpful is there any way to read the class name and student details 
Please find the attached file [Test.xlsx](https://cloud.degoo.com/e/drive-74zsdjy-xhlw)

Comment: The example that you have shared, is it the excel or the dataframe that you get after importing the excel? In either case, can you also share the other?

Comment: it's the content from excel I added column names also at the top

Comment: Post the `Test.xlsx` as well. It is difficult to say if there is improper reading of the file.

Comment: No there isn't. Write a separate script to split your file into smaller ones by looking for the column name "Class" in the line. You can read each file in a loop with pandas.

Comment: @Sathish Sanjeevi added the file

Comment: @SwarajSomala I see. I really doubt that you can create two dataframes out of a single xlsx file. It should be possible to by doing some "tricks" but why not keep them in separate files? There are several posts about combining multiple dataframes into a single file but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample code which iterate and create a dictionary with nested structure.
You can create a needed structure according to you, in this way:-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx',  skiprows=2,names=['A', 'B', 'C','D','E'])
print(df)
finalDict={}
currentClass = ''
currentStudent = ''
for row in df.iterrows():
   if row[1]['A'] == 'Class':
       currentClass = row[1]['B']
       finalDict[currentClass] = {'students' : {}}
   elif row[1]['B'] == 'StudentID':
       currentStudent = row[1]['C']
       currentStudentName = row[1]['E']
       finalDict[currentClass]['students'][currentStudent]={'StudentID': currentStudent, 'StudentName' : currentStudentName,'marks': []}
   elif row[1]['C'] == 'Eng' or row[1]['C'] == 'Mat' or row[1]['C'] == 'Phy':
       DateOfTest = row[1]['B'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       TestDuration = row[1]['E'].strftime("%H:%M:%S")
       finalDict[currentClass]['students'][currentStudent]['marks'].append(
           {'DateOfTest':DateOfTest,
            'TestTitle':row[1]['C'],
            'TestMarks':row[1]['D'],
            'TestDuration':TestDuration}
       )
print("\nOUTPUT:\n")
print(finalDict)
```

which outputs something like:-

```
{
  'First': {
    'students': {
      1: {
        'StudentID': 1,
        'StudentName': 'Name1',
        'marks': [{'DateOfTest': '2019-02-12','TestTitle': 'Eng','TestMarks': 90,'TestDuration': '12:30:00'},....]
      }
    }
  },
  'Second': {
    'students': {
      2: {
        'StudentID': 2,
        'StudentName': 'Name2',
        'marks': [{},.....]
      }
    }
  }
}
```